# Android Draw ImageViiew from OnDraw

Tags: android, android-layout

```
Hi
```

How can I draw an ImageView from the OnDraw() method? canvas.() does not have to call a resource?

I am trying to do this

```
    @Override    
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {         
          super.onDraw(canvas);        
         imageBack = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);             

     canvas.drawBitmap(imageBack, (x /2)-15 ,y /2, null);          
   //touchEvents();        
     ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your ImageView to a bitmap

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01); 
    image1.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = image1.getDrawingCache();
```

You can then draw bmap

Comment: I get an error on the line image1.buldDrawCache(); a null pointer exception ::(

Comment: Then R.id.ImageView01 is not a referenceable object in your current view...you either need to add it through view.addView() or inflate it from xml and then get the reference from your inflated view

Comment: Omg inflated is new to me..., where would i add that line of code view.addView(); in the ondraw?